# symfony2 getting the user provider from the service container

Tags: security, symfony

I need to get a user provider in a controller in Symfony2.
I've got multiple user_providers, with 1 chain-provider chaining those.

There is a service defined in the container with the name `security.user.provider.concrete.XXX` (where XXX is what you specified in security.yml), but that service is marked as private.

I've managed to define an alias in the extension class of my bundle:

```
    $container->setAlias('my_bundle.user.provider', new Alias('security.user.provider.concrete.XXX')));
```

But I rather do it in a more nice way.

So, I got a couple of questions:

- Is there a service I can use to fetch a specific user-provider? Which one?
- If not, is there a simple way (in a pre-compiler-pass or something) to fetch all user-provider names and simply create Aliases for those services?

Comment: Uou can define your own provider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and pass it onto any other service as argument. Without all those dances with aliases and etc.

Comment: Defining your own custom chain provider would be a bit of a problem. Also, it would be better if I could fetch any user_provider without the requirement to define your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played with the configuration a little, and figured out how to generically create aliasses for any providers configured using a `CompilerPass`:

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class TestCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $securityConfig = $container->getExtensionConfig('security');
        foreach ($securityConfig[0]['providers'] as $providerName => $providerConfig) {
            $container->setAlias('my_security.provider.' . $providerName, new Alias('security.user.provider.concrete.' . $providerName));
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to your Bundle class:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // call parent
    parent::build($container);

    // run extra compilerPass
    $container->addCompilerPass(new TestCompilerPass());
}
```

This will create an alias for each UserProvider that is present. It will be available under the key: `my_security.provider.XXX` where XXX is the name configured in your security.yml.

I'm however unsure why the config is prepended with an array with key `0`.
I'm also not really sure if this is a good approach. If nothing better comes up I will be using this solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific provider by the current loggedin users firewall name:

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
$providerKey = $token->getProviderKey(); // secured_area / firewall name
```

You can get see it here: https://codedump.io/share/unA0SxVxuP9v

Comment: This only returns the provider key; I need the actual provider.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to retrieve any user_provider, not just the one applicable to the current firewall. I also need it in a Command sometimes.